# Redirect rule with exclude subdomain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Trying to set the redirect rule which would force redirect for everything with the exception of one sub domain and one web page:

```
<rules>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www1\.mywebsite\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/file\.txt$" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
 <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
  <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
  <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
 </rule>
</outboundRules>
```